# Какие есть best practises при документировании взаимодействия frontend-backend?

Tags: php, ajax, сервер, frontend

Добрый день, в проекте бекенд-девелопер хочет получить запросы которые будут отсылатся с фронта и ответ от бекенда. но толком что ему нужно объяснить видимо не способен, или же не хочет. подскажите пожалуйста есть ли какие-то стандартные практики каким образом лучше документировать эти вещи и как это оформлять
единственно что удалось выбить пока это пример запроса

```
form_data = $("#your_form").serialize();
$.post("/_ajax.php", {token: $('#f_token').attr("content"), file: 'constructor', 
data: 
 {
    items: ['CO037EWIRW04IN', 'CO037EWILA28IN']
  tags: {id:1; id:2; }
  sex:1
  type_body:1
  color: 4
  category:6
}
}, function(r) {
           try {
               result = jQuery.parseJSON(r);
           } catch(err){
               alert(err);
           }
           if (result.status == "success") {
               alert(result.mes);
           } else {
               alert(result.mes);
           }
});
```

Comment: Интересная ситуация ... обычно бэкэнд девелопер определяет что можно у АПИ спрашивать, делать и как это отдавать. Попробуйте с ним пообщаться в терминологии REST - самый простой вариант. Т/е определите ресурсы, которые присутствуют в приложении (опять же это вопрос к бэкэнду... фронту то какое дело - ему лишь показать это нужно грамотно), определите что можно делать с этими ресурсами. Ну и далее: POST api/v1/posts, PUT api/v1/posts/1, GET api/v1/posts, GET api/v1/posts/1 и т/п по ситуации.

Comment: бекендер не признает рест. может делать только обработку запросов общего типа в варианте stateful

Comment: @xtfkpi бекеднд должен определять логику, а не фронтенд. Иначе выйдет полная каша. Если фронтендщику что-то нужно что нет в бекенде (или плохо/неудобно реализовано) - он делает просьбу реализации в бекенде, но - как реализовать, уже решают бекендщики. Придумывают так - чтобы задача фронта могла быть выполнена, а новый функционал был гибким и мог бы использоваться за рамками задачи.

Comment: ну на фронте тоже есть определенная логика взаимодействия. поэтому пока еще в процессе синхронизации

Answer (score 2):

Все стандарты описания web-сервисов крутятся вокруг REST или SOAP. Ваш случай -- определённо ближе REST, как минимум потому что у вас JSON используется для передачи ответа. Могу порекомендовать язык [RAML](http://raml.org/) для которого есть масса инструметов (и для [генерации документации](http://raml.org/developers/document-your-api) в том числе).

То что у вас нет отдельных адресов для ресурсов - совсем не проблема. Все-равно же есть какие-то отдельные ajax-методы, просто договоритесь, что `/path/to/action` будет обозначать что-нибудь типа `/ajax.php?route=path/to/action`.

И то что сервис не stateless тоже не должно помешать вам оформлять документацию в нотации RAML.

Я даже думаю что со временем сам стандарт описания будет вас подталкивать к правильному офомлению серверной части. Однин из способов применения RAML, к стати, это как раз [проектирование API](http://raml.org/developers/design-your-api).